# Compile vb.net application in to standalone .exe

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compilation

I've been digging around for an answer to this problem. It seems like a simple use case.

I have a very simple vb.net console application in Visual Studio 2019. I want to compile it in to a standalone .exe file.

When I compile the application several files are generated.

```
myprogram.deps.json
myprogram.dll
myprogram.exe
myprogram.pdb
myprogram.runtimeconfig.dev.json
myprogram.runtimeconfig.json
```

I find that if I don't include `myprogram.dll` and `myprogram.runtimeconfig.json` with `myprogram.exe` I am unable to execute the application. I have tried both debug and release versions.

How can I compile this simple application in to a single .exe file with no other dependencies other than the .net framework which is already on every modern Windows computer?

Comment: What are the `Imports` that you are using? It doesn't seem to be a "simple" application if it requires `json`.

Comment: @daShier it is very simple. Let’s consider this a “hello world” example. I created a new vb.net console application in VS and compiled it. I’m on the road but I believe the only import in there (added by default) is system.

Comment: Then it would appear that something has been added to your project in VS. I would check the Project References page to see what you might be dragging in that you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be attempting to use CORE 3.0.
In that case you may want to consider using the "--self-contained" flag.

[Refer](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/)

Comment: While not directly a solution, your post helped me to realize that I had selected a .net core console application rather than a .net framework console application. After creating a new project and copying the code over, I was able to compile a simple standalone .exe. I also found that the .net core application was failing to run on another computer because .net core was missing. Thanks.